# GC.KeepAlive. Different MSDN articles for different versions. Did they change anything?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

The article for .NET Framework v.2 contains two examples.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.keepalive(v=vs.80).aspx

The first one is of particular interest as it helps with understanding of Garbage Collector behavior.

But other versinos do not contain similar example. What changed in .NET Framework GC for missing example became not actual?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but it's interesting that the example is also gone from the .NET 3.0 and 3.5 documentation. .NET 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5 are all the same CLR version.

Comment: @hvd. Yes, interesting, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see nothing in that example became invalid with later versions.

I would guess they were motivated by one of two reasons:

1. The example code isn't very useful (though it **does** demonstrate what it's there to demonstrate), and has no practical effect but to waste memory, it could then become another thing encouraging people to do bizarre things with `GC` that makes things less performant.
2. Example code are another piece of code that has to be tested, maintained and bug-fixed. Remove an example, and reduce your testing and bug-fixing overhead.